# Generating unique 16 characters GUID

Tags: unique, abap, guid

Please help me in generating a unique 16 characters GUID which I could use as a primary key in my custom table.

I have tried with `GUID_CREATE` and `CL_SYSTEM_UUID~CREATE_UUID_X16` but its exporting parameters(`EV_GUID_16`) are returning 32 characters(alphanumeric hexdecimal value) which i cannot assign to my 16 characters variable.

How could I convert 16 lenght(32 characters) raw text to 16 characters string which I could use as a primary key?

Answer (score 4):

The methods you mentioned do create a 16-byte GUID. Since this cannot be displayed "natively", it is converted to a hexadecimal notation which naturally will use two characters per byte, hence the 32 characters. You probably won't get anything unique using only 16 characters (not bytes - there's a huge difference!) - if possible, enlarge your primary key to 32 characters.

Comment: I was able to generate a 16 characters unique id by using the function module 'CRR_GET_RANDOM_STRING'. This has solved my requirement.

Comment: @user2999223 This id will not be unique, it is just random or to be more accurate, pseudorandom.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the type of primary key of your transparent table to RAW16. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Using `RAW` fields in the primary key is usually a bad idea - for instance, you can't specifiy individual records when transporting table entries. (I wish the Object Services guys had thought of this when they imposed their `OS_GUID`s on us...)

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting, because for example a **standard** SAP table `BCA_CONTRACT` in SAP Banking Services contains GUID as RAW 16 which is part of primary key of this table. Moreover this key is used in other tables as a primary and foreign key as well.

Comment: I don't have a banking installation available, but I suspect that's one of the OS_GUID fields. They do work fine, but a lot of standard tools (maintenance dialogs, transport, system comparison, ...) will either produce unexpected results or stop working altogether as soon as a RAW GUID is part of the table. I've learned this the hard way, so I thought I'd leave a heads-up...

Comment: I think I know, what you are talking about. I saw this problem in the test tool of `SE37`. This is why the BAPIs that deal with the data provided in the tables I mentioned, have the GUID specified as CHAR 32. Cannot say much about the maintenance views as all of this tables are application data. The generated selection screen for `SE16` however seems to be dealing fine with this kind of data element containing RAW type (the field is converted to CHAR 32).

Comment: BTW: the function BANK_DISTRIBUTED_ID_CREATE is used to create GUIDs in SAP banking systems because  cl_system_uuid=>create_uuid_x16_static( ) does not produce homogenous ie evenly spread GUIDs. This a major weakness. Uniqueness of GUID is not questioned, But when it is NOT evenly spread it is a VERY POOR index field.  This is a critical weakness in high volume tables. (eg banking)

Comment: @philsoady Been there, done that. In one of the project I took part in, some genius implemented parallel processing using BUT000-GUID for splitting. Our migrated business partners run afterwards for hours in one process, because for the others 0 instances were selected.

Answer (score 1):

GUID_CREATE was already mentioned. Once you have got a GUID in RAW format, you can use GUID_CONVERT to move it to CHAR format. I would not recommend using RAW in the primary key and would suggest using only GUID_32 (char format) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an unique Id create you own 'Z...' number range object with transaction `SNUM`.
Set `Number Length Domain` to  NUM16 or any domain that meets your requirement.
Save and go back to transaction `SNUM` main screen. From there, maintain the intervals : ex 01 from 1 to 999999... and save. To transport your new **intervals** values, select the transport option from the menu.

In Abap , to get an unique ID call function `NUMBER_GET_NEXT` as below:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'NUMBER_GET_NEXT'
EXPORTING
  nr_range_nr             = **'01'     " << put your number interval   here <<**
  object                  = **'Z.....' " << put your number range name here <<**
IMPORTING
  number                  = e_uniqueid
EXCEPTIONS
  interval_not_found      = 1
  number_range_not_intern = 2
  object_not_found        = 3
  quantity_is_0           = 4
  quantity_is_not_1       = 5
  interval_overflow       = 6
  buffer_overflow         = 7
  OTHERS                  = 8.
```

Comment: Just make sure to disable the "to-year flag" to avoid that the number starts with 1 again next year. Keep the buffering enabled to increase performance.

Comment: OP is specifically asking about GUIDs, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

We can use the FM 'CRR_GET_RANDOM_STRING' to generate a 16 characters unique id.

Comment: Jolly good but this function module is not available in every SAP system. In mine for example it is not.

Comment: I do not have any possibility to look at the code of that FM but as in the case of PATRY answer, I highly doubt that this string in unique, it is just random. So really if you do not want to have any surprises when the code reaches production, please switch to RAW 16 key in your table and generate the UUID by `CL_SYSTEM_UUID~CREATE_UUID_X16`. You could also switch to CHAR 32 as vwegert suggested and then use `CL_SYSTEM_UUID~CREATE_UUID_C32`.

Answer (score -3):

The module function "GENERAL_GET_RANDOM_STRING" can also be used, if you need a unique 16 *char* id

Comment: The question is whether this random string provides at least such a uniqueness as GUID itself.

Comment: A random number is not guaranteed to be unique. This is not a solution, just a flawed workaround (sorry).

Comment: it's true, so nothing to be soryy about. Even if the probability of having 2 16char string identical is low, it still exists.